# Center an image inside another image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added an image with class "img-circle". I need to put another small image at the center of this image which is center for all devices.

Can any one tell me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DEMO: **http://jsbin.com/IyAkoYA/2**

```
<!-- begin image within image :: background size cover does not work in IE make sure you don't exceed the width of the actual image -->

 <div class="circle-wrapper">
  <span class="force-ratio"></span>
  <div class="img-container align-center">
   <div class="center-block-valign"></div>
   <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/250x250/000000&text=image+2" alt="">
   </div><!--img-container align-center-->
  </div><!--circle-wrapper--> 

 <!-- end image within image -->


.circle-wrapper * {
 box-sizing:content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box 
}

.circle-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing:content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box 
 background-image:url(http://placehold.it/400x400/ff6600/FFFFFF&text=image+1);
 background-position:50% 50%;
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat:none;
 border-radius:50%;
 max-width:400px;
 max-height:400px;
}

 .force-ratio {
 padding-top: 100%;
 display:block;
 }

.img-container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.align-center {
 text-align:center;
 font: 0/0 a;
}

.center-block-valign {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 100%;
}

.circle-wrapper .img-circle {
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 max-width:50%;
 padding:25%;
}
```

Much of this was found by googling "center responsive image inside another image" from this http://jsbin.com/aXiReCub/1/edit. Then, because BS3 uses a global border-box sizing, adjustments need to be made among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Add following css code to your css file

```
.img-circle{position:relative}
anothor-image-selector:{position:absolute;margin:auto;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0}
```

for **pro** and **cons** of this method just visit following article :

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: Thanks, I used  the above css, but when i resize the browser, the second image position is moving, not fixed at the center of the first image

Answer (score 0):

```
box-sizing:contant-box;
```

use this code. I hope help you.

Comment: can u explain more on that

Comment: background-position:50% 50%; use

Comment: box-sizing:content-box. Fix the spelling.